# How I Can Send the status of switch in SMS by Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

How I want help ,, I want send status of Switch If switch > 20 send SMS status of switch OFF and when switch <20 than mean switch ON , Don't want send the value of reading.
I use Arduino uno

If I want use multiple switch and send all status of switchs in one message.
I mean if switch1 > 20 ON and switch2 <20
I want send status of switch In one SMS
Switch1 ON
Switch2 OFF
Switch3 OFF

How I can do this??

```
void loop() 
Switch = analogRead(S_Switch);
if (Switch > 20 )
{
Serial.println(Switch);// If Switch > 20 show in SMS switch statuse  OFF,, If switch < 20 show in SMS switch statuse ON
Serial.print("\n******************\n");
Sim900Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r"); //Sending the SMS in text mode
delay(1000);
Sim900Serial.println("AT + CMGS = \"+***************\"");//The predefined phone number
delay(1000);
Sim900Serial.println("MY Swicth statuse is :");
Sim900Serial.println(Switch); // I don't want the value of Switch I want ( ON , OFF )
 Sim900Serial.print("              ");
Sim900Serial.println((char)26);//the ASCII code of the ctrl z is 26
delay(5000);
Sim900Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to send the value in both cases, ON and OFF?  Do you just want it to keep sending constantly, over and over, or some other behaviour (e.g. when it changes)?  Does your existing code work (but not do what you want)?

Answer (score 1):

Here, Updated Code...

```
const int switchOneInput = A0; // Switch 1
const int switchTwoInput = A1; // Switch 2

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  int switchOneStatus = analogRead(A0);
  int switchTwoStatus = analogRead(A1);

  // When Switch 1 is OFF and Switch 2 is OFF
  if(switchOneStatus < 20 && switchTwoStatus < 20)
  {
    smsOne();
  }

  // When Switch 1 is ON and Switch 2 is OFF
  else if(switchOneStatus > 20 && switchTwoStatus < 20)
  {
    smsTwo();
  }

  // When Switch 1 is OFF and Switch 2 is ON
  else if(switchOneStatus < 20 && switchTwoStatus > 20)
  {
    smsThree();
  }

  // When Switch 1 is ON and Switch 2 is ON
  else if(switchOneStatus > 20 && switchTwoStatus > 20)
  {
    smsFour();
  }


}

void smsOne()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);  //Baud rate of the GSM/GPRS Module 
  Serial.print("\r");
  delay(1000);                  
  Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");    
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"+**********\"\r");    //Number to which you want to send the sms
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("Switch 1 is OFF and Switch 2 is OFF\r");   //The text of the message to be sent
  delay(1000);
  Serial.write(0x1A);
  delay(1000);
}

void smsTwo()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);  //Baud rate of the GSM/GPRS Module 
  Serial.print("\r");
  delay(1000);                  
  Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");    
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"+**********\"\r");    //Number to which you want to send the sms
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("Switch 1 is ON and Switch 2 is OFF\r");   //The text of the message to be sent
  delay(1000);
  Serial.write(0x1A);
  delay(1000);
}

void smsThree()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);  //Baud rate of the GSM/GPRS Module 
  Serial.print("\r");
  delay(1000);                  
  Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");    
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"+**********\"\r");    //Number to which you want to send the sms
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("Switch 1 is OFF and Switch 2 is ON\r");   //The text of the message to be sent
  delay(1000);
  Serial.write(0x1A);
  delay(1000);
}

void smsFour()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);  //Baud rate of the GSM/GPRS Module 
  Serial.print("\r");
  delay(1000);                  
  Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");    
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"+**********\"\r");    //Number to which you want to send the sms
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("Switch 1 is ON and Switch 2 is ON\r");   //The text of the message to be sent
  delay(1000);
  Serial.write(0x1A);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks dear but still you don't understand me this I can use just for one switch ON or OFF , if more than one switch ,, And I want both status in one SMS

Comment: I mean both status Switch1 ON or OFF and Switch2 ON or OFF In same SMS. Example Switch1 ON , Switch2 ON

Comment: Ok. Got it. You mean like if Switch 1 is ON or OFF then SMS you notify you about Switch 1 is ON or OFF. And now if you add another Switch let say Switch 2. So, now suppose Switch 1 is ON and Switch 2 is OFF then SMS be like `Switch 1 is ON and Switch 2 is OFF`. Am I right ?

Comment: Thanks Hasan,, Yes and send in one SMS so any change in switch will change in SMS

Comment: Ok. Got it. Let me modified my code.

Comment: I just modified my code. I hope it will help  you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53609/discussion-between-moosa-alismaili-and-hasan).